# ActionBlock Framework 4 rx alternative

Tags: c#, system.reactive, tpl-dataflow

I'm interested in an ActionBlock implementation for Framework 4.0, since there it seems that TPL.Dataflow isn't supported for Framework 4.0.
More particularly, I'm interested in the case of the constructor that receives the Func<TInput, Task> delegate and the MaxDegreeOfParallism = 1 case.

I thought about implementing it using reactive extensions, but I'm not sure how to do it. Thought about creating a Subject<TInput> and calling OnNext on Post, and using SelectMany and task ToObservable stuff, but I'm not sure what to do with the scheduler. Here is a draft of what I was thinking of.

```cs
public class ActionBlock<TInput>
{
    private readonly TaskCompletionSource<object> mCompletion = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
    private readonly Subject<TInput> mQueue = new Subject<TInput>();

    public ActionBlock(Func<TInput, Task> action)
    {
        var observable =
            from item in mQueue
            from _ in action(item).ToObservable()
            select _;

        observable.Subscribe(x => { },
            OnComplete);
    }

    private void OnComplete()
    {
        mCompletion.SetResult(null);
    }

    public void Post(TInput input)
    {
        mQueue.OnNext(input);
    }

    public Task Completion
    {
        get
        {
            return mCompletion.Task;
        }
    }

    public void Complete()
    {
        mQueue.OnCompleted();
    }
}
```

I thought maybe using EventLoopScheduler but I'm not sure it fits here since this is async.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
mQueue
    .Select(input => Observable.FromAsync(() => action(input))
    .Merge(maxDegreeOfParallelism)
    .Subscribe(...);
```

If indeed `maxDegreeOfParallelism` is always 1, then just use `Concat` instead of `Merge`:

```
mQueue
    .Select(input => Observable.FromAsync(() => action(input))
    .Concat()
    .Subscribe(...);
```

This works because `FromAsync` just creates a cold observable that will not run the async action until it is subscribed.  We then use the `maxConcurrency` parameter of `Merge` (or just `Concat`) to limit the number of concurrent subscriptions (and thus the number of async actions running).

Edit:

And since your goal is to just have a `Task` that represents the completion of the stream, you can use `ToTask` instead of directly subscribing.  `ToTask` will subscribe and return a `Task` with the final value.  Because `ToTask` will throw if the observable does not produce a value, we'll use `Count` to guarantee it produces a value:

```
// task to mark completion
private readonly Task mCompletion;

// ...

this.mCompletion = mQueue
    .Select(input => Observable.FromAsync(() => action(input))
    .Concat()
    .Count()
    .ToTask();
```